# Convert some date string into NSDate

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate

From server I am receiving date string like - **Date(1432224879000)**

Can someone please help me to convert above string into NSDate.

Comment: Hello Akshay :- Have you get ans from these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server return the date into this formate so you need to trim the Date and () and get the actual number which is timestamp since the 1970 and then you can convert it to NSdate, I have used a simple method for this

```
- (NSDate*) converDateStringToNSDate:(NSString *)string
{
// Expect date in this format "/Date(1268123461843)/"
int start = [string rangeOfString:@"("].location+1;
int end = [string rangeOfString:@")"].location;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(start,end-start);
unsigned long long milliseconds = [[string substringWithRange:range] longLongValue];
NSLog(@"%llu",milliseconds);
NSTimeInterval interval = milliseconds/1000;
return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
}
```